# How many iterations does it take to cover a range with random values?

Tags: probability, random, expectation

Let's say I have a random number generator that generates integers uniformly from 0 to n-1 (where n is some positive integer). What is the expected number of iterations after which all the values 0..n-1 will be generated? I did some simulations and the results seem close to n*ln(n), but I wonder how to solve it mathematically.
[Possibly related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806981/after-how-many-iteration-securerandom-will-generate-all-the-number-between-given)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  See the link for details and references.  You are right that asymptotically, the expected number of trials needed grows as $n \ln n$ (plus lower order terms).

Comment: Ah, the harmonic series, of course